# How to combine two sparsematrix using java colt lib?

Tags: colt

I'm using java colt library for sparse matrix. 
Inputs are the two sparse matrix with the same row number, e.g.,

```js
SparseDoubleMatrix1D v1; //[1 2]
SparseDoubleMatrix1D v2; // [3, 4]
```

After some calculation of v1, and v2. I want to append the result of v2 to v1 or they can also be assigned to another new matrix, e.g.,

```js
v3 = [v1; v2] ; // [1 2 3 4]
```

Any one know how to achieve this with colt? Is there an existing method for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answers, I find some solution by using DoubleFactory2D.sparse.appendColumns method in colt lib. details as below:

```
  SparseDoubleMatrix2D v1 = new SparseDoubleMatrix2D(new double[][]{{0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}});
  SparseDoubleMatrix2D v2 = new SparseDoubleMatrix2D(new double[][]{{0, 1}, {1, 1}});
  SparseDoubleMatrix2D matrix = (SparseDoubleMatrix2D) DoubleFactory2D.sparse.appendColumns(v1, v2);
```